# Conditional params in Thinking Sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, parameters

I'm attempting to apply conditional params to a thinking sphinx search.

This is what im trying to achieve (psuedo(ish) code).

I realise this is probably a dumb question or that i'm going about it in the wrong way. But any help would be great.

```
DistributerGame.search :conditions => {:game_genre => @genre *** IF PARAMS[GENRE] EXISTS ***}, :with => {:distributer_id => @distributer_id *** if PARAMS[DISTRIBUTER] EXISTS ***, :price_in_gbp => @price  ***  if PARAMS[PRICE] EXISTS ***}
```

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:game_genre] = @genre if params[:genre].present?
withs = {}
withs[:distibuter_id] = @distributer_id if params[:distibuter].present?
withs[:price_in_gbp] = @price if params[:price].present?
# ...
DistributerGame.search :conditions => conditions, :with => withs
```

**To persevere your `params` over different pages**:

```
#in your view:   
filter_params = {}
filter_params[:game_genre] = params[:genre] if params[:genre].present?
filter_params[:distibuter] = params[:distibuter] if params[:distibuter].present?
filter_params[:price_in_gbp] = params[:price] if params[:price].present?

@distributers.each do |d|
  filters_params[:distibuter] = d.id
  link_to d.name, filter_params # you may have to merge this with your resource_path

@genres.each do |g|
  filter_params[:genre] = g.id
  link_to g.name, filter_params
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to have worked. My next question is that the params aren't being remembered. Asin as soon as i send a 'genre' param the 'distributer' param is lost. Do you know how I would keep this?

Comment: that's weird ... From where do you call this method?

Comment: It's in a controller. I figure I just need to store my params in a session so that they persevere?

Comment: Oh no that's a bad idea (the session could be very big at the end). I guess you are talking about keeping filter params over pages? Like you choose "distributer = Ubisoft", then the page reload with `?distibuter_id=1` params and if you click on "game_genre = Action", the page reloads with `params[:game_genre]` but lost the `params[:distributer_id]` , is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yeah thats what's happening :)

Comment: Hmm well I'll update my post with a way to persevere it in a sec ;) What kind of input are you using to choose the filters? Select boxes? Link_to ?

Comment: There will be various eventually. For now im just using link_to - This will eventually be ajaxified.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can see now a way to persevere params over pages